Insert values from a list of dictionaries using SQLAlchemy Postgres in python
I have a table in RDS (aurora postgres) that looks like this:
students:



student_id (pk)
student_name
number_of_classes_taken
one_violation
multiple_violation




1234
joe_smith
1
False
False


5678
jane_smith
9
True
True



I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:
students = [
{"student_id": "1234", "name": "joe_smith", "classes_added": 1},
{"student_id": "5678", "name": "jane_smith", "classes_added": 3},
{"student_id": "9012", "name": "jenny_smith", "classes_added": 5}
]

I want to insert the students from the list of dictionaries that aren't already in the table while updating the ones that are. If a student exists, I want to update the column for number_of_classes_taken to be the sum of the existing integer in the row and the integer for classes_added in the dictionary. So for joe_smith, it would be 2 (1 existing + 1 added). For jane_smith it would be 12 (9 existing + 3 added).
For students that aren't in the table, I just want to insert them and set number_of_classes_taken to the value for classes_added.
Ideally, if this is possible, I would also like to update one_violation to True for anyone taking more than 6 classes and multiple_violation to True for anyone taking more than 7 classes. Otherwise set them both to False. On inserts of new students, I'd like both of these to be set to False by default. If this is not possible in the same query/call, It can be done separately.
So far I've tried:
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgressql import insert

# Iterate the list of students to be added
for student in students:
    insert_stmt = insert(students).values(
        student_id={student['student_id']}, 
        student_name={student['name']}, 
        number_of_classes_taken={student['classes_added']},
        one_violation={False},
        multiple_violation={False})
    # If a student exists based off the primary key (the student_id) update the row with the sum(classes_added + number_of_classes_taken) and update the one_violation and multiple_violation column if the student has more than 6 or more than 7 classes
    do_update_stmt = insert_stmt.on_conflict_do_update(
        constraint="student_id_pk",
        set_=dict(number_of_classes_taken=student["classes_added"], one_violation=??,                                            multiple_violation=??),
        )

This attempt came from here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert
I think I am close but I can't figure it out. I also do not know how to do the sum() for classes taken or how to update the one_violation and multiple_violation off that value. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this in one call to the DB, otherwise it's fine to do the insert/update in one call and the updating of one_violation and multiple_violation in another.
I am also open to other approaches if there's a better way to do this. My connection to RDS is done through SQLAlchemy create_engine and this works.
I'm pretty new to SQLAlchemy so any help is appreciated.
